# How to upload artifacts to maven central with gradle and the maven plugin via a proxy

Tags: gradle, proxy, mavendeployer

I try to upload some artifacts to maven central ([well actually to the sonatyp repository](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/releasing-the-deployment.html#releasing-deployment-from-ossrh-to-the-central-repository-introduction)) using gradle.

I set up my build file as described in [this nice article](http://yennicktrevels.com/blog/2013/10/11/automated-gradle-project-deployment-to-sonatype-oss-repository/)

And it worked for quite some time, but now I'm sitting behind a proxy, and the only information how to configure the proxy is a snippet that there is a `proxy` element in the configuration and [its JavaDoc](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/Proxy.html)

But I don't now how to actually translate that into code in my build file

I tried many variations of

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(...) {...}

            proxy('https://myproxy:8080'){
                authentication(userName: proxyUser, password: proxyPassword)
            }
...
```

But all I get are messages that no matching proxy method was found.

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're almost there. The proxy setup must be within the repository configuration block:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url:"http://someupload.url"){
                proxy(host: "localhost", port: 8080, type: 'http', userName:"proxyusername", password:"proxypassword")
            }
        }
    }
}
```